# cannot see the rows which are deleted in another session

Tags: oracle

I have a sentence which is deleting some rows for some time (few hours).
From other session I interogate the table which is deleted and now rows are displayed.

Can someone enlight me with an explanation or a link to a documentation where I can find the reason why in 2nd session I cannot see any row?

Thank you,

Comment: You cannot see or can see?

Comment: I cannot see any row, even if the delete statement from 1st session has not finished.

Comment: No dirty reads is what it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reported behaviour is explained under the topics data concurrency and consistency.

In essence,

> A multiuser database must provide the following:
>
> The assurance that users can access data at the same time (data
> concurrency)
>
> The assurance that each user sees a consistent view of the data (data
> consistency), including visible changes made by the user's own
> transactions and committed transactions of other users
>
> Oracle Database never permits a dirty read, which occurs when a transaction reads uncommitted data in another transaction.

Please read the [this explanation](http://mrbool.com/oracle-data-concurrency-and-consistency/28518). Official documentation is [here](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CNCPT/consist.htm#CNCPT020)